# error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 'DetailedHTMLProps'. But in @types/react : type DetailedHTMLProps is indeed defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my react-typescript-electron project I have:

```
@types/react": "^17.0.0"
"react": "^17.0.1"
```

In a .tsx file I imported react and created a type Props:

```
import React from 'react';
type Props = React.DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>
```

I get this error:

```
error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 'DetailedHTMLProps'
```

But in /node_modules/@types/react DetailedHTMLProps is indeed defined:

```
type DetailedHTMLProps<E extends HTMLAttributes<T>, T> = ClassAttributes<T> & E;
```

If I add in the .tsx file:

```
interface Props_two {
  summary: React.ReactNode;
  children: () => React.ReactNode;
}
```

I get a similar error:

```
error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 'ReactNode'
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: It's defined but not *exported*, by the looks of it.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe ! I added export in node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts : export type DetailedHTMLProps<E extends HTMLAttributes<T>, T> = ClassAttributes<T> & E; but I get the same error:  error TS2694: Namespace '"react"' has no exported member 'DetailedHTMLProps'